# Calling a Function with integer [[mayb_unused]] macro and default argument boolean type parameter

Tags: c++, default-parameters, option-type

I am writing a Function with 2 Parameters, 1st is integer type marked [[maybe_unused]] and 2nd is Boolean Type with Default Argument false.

```
int preOrderTraversial([[maybe_unused]] int searchData, bool forDisplay = false)
```

This is the function declaration. The function is used for pre-order Traversal in Binary Search Tree. I want to use the same function for Displaying the Tree and Traversing it for searching a Node with specific Data. But only for 1 of both problems at once. Not for searching AND displaying you see.

So, obviously, it works fine for the searching part but when I call the function for Displaying the function call looks like this:

```
preOrderTraversal(true)
```

or

```
bool forDisplay = true;
preOrderTraversal(forDisplay);
```

Now the Compiler (even with the parameter DECLARED as a BOOL) still considers this bool parameter as an int and uses it for searchData (integer) parameter of the function and not for the forDisplay (bool) parameter.

Is there a way to force or tell compiler which of both parameters I am trying to work with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[[maybe_unused]]` means that the **function body** may not use it, *but* the signature of the function always have it. Actually event the default value for the boolean does not modify the signature of your function; Thus your function *always* take 2 arguments, the first being a integer, and the second being a boolean (that may be set to the default if you didn't put it). You end up with calling:

```
bool forDisplay = true;
preOrderTraversal(/* integer searchData; bool geting casted to int */ forDisplay,
                  false /* the forDisplay (2nd param) default value*/);
```

which does not meet your expectations.

[EDIT]
how to overcome?
There is not builtin way to use named parameters in C++ but you may workaround using a helper class:

```
struct PreOrderTraversal {
  bool _forDisplay = false;
  int _searchData = 0; /* FIXME What is the default here? */
  auto& forDisplay() { _forDisplay = true; return *this; }
  auto& searchData(int x) { _searchData = x; return *this; }

  void run() { if (_forDisplay) ;//do the right things
               else ;// use data

  }
};
```

then you can use it with:

```
PreOrderTraversal().forDisplay().run();
PreOrderTraversal().searchData(123).run();
```

This kinda mimics that named parameter feature.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I am trying to overcome. Is there a way to get around this problem?

Comment: Yep! I can totally use that . Just wanted to do it differently from others, just as a challenge, but then I got stuck lol. Thanks for the help